# Tests failing in TestLab, but passing in local when Passing arguments from runner from gradle and using them in my androidTest

Tags: android, arguments, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab, androidjunitrunner

I am passing arguments from runner through gradle and using them in my androidTest.

'''
e;g:

```
In build.gradle:    
android {
          defaultConfig {
                testInstrumentationRunnerArguments 'FOO' :'foo'
           }
       }

 In androidTest/foo.java
     username= androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry.getArguments().getString("FOO");
```

The test is working locally, but when running in Firebase TestLab, I am getting a null pointer exception and tests failing when I am trying to access argument with key=FOO. Can you please help me with this issue.

I do not want to use CLI. If there is a way I can do this using android studio and firebase testlab web UI, please let me know.

Comment: how are you executing your tests on Firebase test lab? via CLI? via Android Studio? via web UI?

Comment: Hi  yogurtearl , I am creating the apk's in android studio. Then uploading the test and app apk into Firebase test lab console (web UI) and running the tests. I do not want to use CLI as it is a paid service . If there is a way I can do this using android studio and firebase testlab web UI, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

[You can pass them in by running tests thru the command line:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/command-line)

Use the `--environment-variables` option.

```
gcloud firebase test android run \
  --type instrumentation \
  --app app-debug.apk \
  --test app-debug-test.apk \ 
  --environment-variables FOO=foo
```

Comment: Hi, I do not have google cloud platform paid version and I do not want to buy it at this point. Is there a way I can test it with Firebase test lab itself?

Comment: The command line uses the same account and has the same billing structure. You can run the same free tests from the command line or from Android studio.

Comment: Tests failing due to reasons like device crashed when running from GCI, but when I run directly from test lab console tests pass. What could be the reason?

Comment: There should not be any difference in test result if the tests are submitted with the same options.

Are you sure you are using the same device(s) in both cases? And that your tests are not flakey? What CLI options did you specify?